# How to send Newsletters (bulk emails) asynchronously in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, asynchronous

I need to send about 5000 emails as newsletter to my website users asynchronously.. The problem is i don't know the best way to send them asynchronously ..Please help me updating my code to make it asynchronously

My Code:

```
   public string SendEmail()
    {


        foreach (var emailAddress in EmailList)

        {
            var message = new MailMessage("myemail@gmail.com", emailAddress);

            message.Subject = "hi";
            SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587);
            client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("myemail@gmail.com", "*****");
            client.EnableSsl = true;
            client.Send(message);
        }
        return "done";
    }
```

Thank you , Lucy

Comment: there should be an asynchronous function due to [THIS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/x5x13z6h(v=vs.110).aspx) article

Comment: 1) Create window server
2) Schedule it to execute on 2 min interval
3) Create thread for each email. 

This way you can send emails asynchronously.

Comment: Using async/await in an action method still forces the user to wait for everything to complete. You can use a single Thread in a fire-and-forget manner to do all processing in the background while the user can do other things (even leave your site or close the browser).

Comment: Thank you Rachit ... Can you please tell me how can i make thread for each email... you can use my code. thank you

Comment: @HansKesting, Thank you so much for your helping, Can you please how can i make it in my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the `async` and `await` keywords.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt674882.aspx

> The async and await keywords in C# are the heart of async programming. By using those two keywords, you can use resources in the .NET Framework or the Windows Runtime to create an asynchronous method almost as easily as you create a synchronous method. Asynchronous methods that you define by using async and await are referred to as async methods.

MSDN explains the syntax side of things.  The bigger concern is error handling and reliably.  Dumping 5,000 emails into a list and hitting the "send" button on them is a little optimistic.  Do these emails need to be reliably delivered?  What happens if 3,000 of them send, and a network error suddenly causes temporary connectivity loss to the outgoing mail server?  Are you going to resend all 5,000 when it starts working again? Just forget about the last 2,000?  Are the recipients going to be mad because they got duplicates, or didn't get the message at all?  How are you going to troubleshoot errors?

A pattern that I've found that has worked really well (whether you are sending synchronously or asynchronously), is to generate the messages and store each in a database table, and then use something like the following:

```
public void SendAllEmails()
{
    var emails = SomeClass.GetAllUnsentEmails();

    foreach(Email message in Emails)
    {
        var success = SendEmail(message);

        if (!success)
        {
            // Do you want to do something if it fails?
        }
    }
}

public bool SendEmail(Email message)
{
    try
    {
        // 1. Send the email message
        // 2. Update the "SentOn" date in the database
        // 3. return true
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        SomeClass.CreateEmailErrorEntry(message, ex); // store error in a table or log
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

edit: if it's being used inside of action you should mark your action async

```
public async Task<ActionResult> MyAction()
```

for a start, don't create `SmtpClient` for every message so as follows
and also this, should send the mails asynchronously but wait for all of them to be sent

```
    public string SendEmail()
    {
        var tasks = new List<Task>();
        var client = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587);
        client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("myemail@gmail.com", "*****");
        client.EnableSsl = true;
        foreach (var emailAddress in EmailList)
        {
            var message = new MailMessage("myemail@gmail.com", emailAddress);
            message.Subject = "hi";
            tasks.Add(client.SendMailAsync(message));
        }
        while(tasks.Count > 0)
        {
            var idx = Task.WaitAny(tasks.ToArray());
            tasks.RemoveAt(idx);
        }
        return "done";
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your help and time .... for      tasks.Add(client.SendAsync(message)); it says Argument 1: cannot convert from 'void' to 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task'

Comment: You may want to change to WaitAll if you want to wait for all the tasks to complete before exiting and get rid of the while loop.

Comment: there's no real difference, i'm used to do the loop, because i usually use the result of the task

Comment: Thank you again, but the code is not working it tells me task doesn't work with MVC .. i tihnk i need to make usage of wait and parallel.ForEach

Comment: adding clarification for action